# tilemill creates jagged edges for worldmap

Tags: leaflet, png, qgis, tilemill, cartocss

Trying to create a custom world map texture with tilemill to load into leafletjs. I have downloaded a free .tiff file from [natural earth data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-raster-data/50m-gray-earth/) and loaded it into tilemill. 
When i want to export however, i notice alot of jagged edges mainly around greenland/canada on the lowest zoom level.

[image: jagged eges around greenland/canada]

a few zoom levels down and it seems ok again. After exporting the tiles to png's the jagged edges stay. How can i improve the quality of these images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can i improve the quality of these images?

By using more detailed input data.

By the looks of it, you are projecting a raster image in EPSG:4326 projection into the EPSG:3857 "web mercator" projection. In the original data, each pixel spans the same amount of longitude and latitude degrees. In a mercator projection, each pixel spans the same amount of longitude, but a different amount of latitude. The artifacts you are experiencing are akin to a [Tissot's indicatrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot%27s_indicatrix).

You can try using a different [value for the `raster-scaling` symbolizer option](https://github.com/mapbox/carto/blob/master/docs/latest.md#raster-scaling-keyword) in your tilemill stylesheet, but that's gonna make the artifacts different, not get rid of them.

Comment: Thank you! very interesting. I am very new to all of this so i appreciate the wikipedia link. i understand it now. Natural earth data is indeed in plain vanilla and would need reprojection to mercator. However setting raster-scaling to bilinear improved it by alot! Indeed it is not gone but i think this will do for now.

Comment: Please don't say "plain vanilla", please say "lat-long orthorectangular" instead ;-) Also have a good look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection